# Handle IOS remote notifications if the app is forced quit

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, unusernotificationcenter

I handling the remote notification like the code snippet shown below, but I failed to launch the app and redirect to specific pages when the users force quite the app.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {


        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        let page = userInfo["page"] as! String


        if page == "message"{
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "Messages"), object: nil) }
```

I read from somewhere around here that in appdelegate **didfinishlaunchingwithoptions** we can add a line :

```
    if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] { 
}
```

But I don't know how to extract the message info from this dictionary

Updated for my notification response :

```
 4 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("aps")
      - value : "aps"
    ▿ value : 2 elements
      ▿ 0 : 2 elements
        - key : alert
        ▿ value : 2 elements
          ▿ 0 : 2 elements
            - key : title
            - value : New Message
          ▿ 1 : 2 elements
            - key : body
            - value : You have a new message from John 
      ▿ 1 : 2 elements
        - key : sound
        - value : default
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("gcm.message_id")
      - value : "gcm.message_id"
    - value : 0:
 ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("google.c.a.e")
      - value : "google.c.a.e"
    - value : 1
  ▿ 3 : 2 elements
    ▿ key : AnyHashable("page")
      - value : "page"
    - value : message
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to fetch "page" like this

```
if let remoteNotification = launchOptions?[.remoteNotification] as?  [AnyHashable : Any] {
            if let page = remoteNotification["page"] as? String {
                if page == "message" {

                }
            }
        }
```

**Note - Please show your notification response that you get in app if this didn't worked**

Comment: Can I please see JSON Format that is printed in Console ?

Comment: bro I think I can get the message data out from the notification, but I think I can't laugh specific screen with specific variable value, is there any ways to do it?

Comment: you mean to launch (Restart App When app is terminated ?) the App. If yes, Its not possible as per apple guidelines. You may need to have Voip services (PushKit) but that won't also directly let you open app

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the launchOptions dictionary from the didfinishlaunchingwithoptions delegate method and then access your notification payload like below. Try to log userInfo dictionary first to see it's content and then access your payload of notification.

var userInfo = launchOptions["UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey"] as? [AnyHashable : Any]
var apsInfo = userInfo?["aps"] as? [AnyHashable : Any]

Comment: is the apsinfo equal to  response.notification.request.content.userInfo in userNotificationCenter?

Comment: No, it's different. From the launchOptions dictionary access the page key.

Comment: it gives me error "Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]' with an index of type 'String'"

Comment: if let notificationPayload = launchOptions? [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? NSDictionary {
            
        }

Comment: Try the above line.